# Parsing returned string with .json() throws an error

Tags: node.js, react-native

My React Native 0.62.3 app receives a string value returned from nodejs 12.16.x. Here is the function on nodejs server:

```
return res.status(200).send(who);  //<<==who is string "seller"
```

At front end, the returned value is received in `res`:

```
 let res = await helper.getAPI(url, _result, "GET");
 let res1 = await res.json();  //<<== here throw error
```

However the above code throws error:

```
isWho :  [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "seller"]
```

I don't quite understand why the value "seller" is treated as `Unexpected identifier`. What is the right way to parse return from nodejs sever for string value?

Comment: It's not JSON, it's plain text. So call `res.text()`.

Comment: You are trying to parse string to JSON, which will definitely throw an error.